# Multiple max lengths in a regular expression

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{1}$
```

I should be able to match the following patterns:

```
1234567-8
3142539-1
```

But not the following:

```
12345678-1
1234567-12
```

Currently my regex matches 12345678-1 but not 1234567-12 (in JavaScript). Both should fail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have a `^` so the pattern can start anywhere.

Comment: @nneonneo Next time, consider writing an answer instead of a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern would match any string that ends(`$`) with `[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{1}` and so it would match those inputs..

Use `^`(start of the string) to specify that you want to match **exactly**..

```
^[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{1}$
```

Comment: Btw: if you want to match a digit from 0 to 9 you can simply use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, so you could shorten the regex to: `^\d{7}-\d$`